# Select data and insert into another table with multiple conditions in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a select statement with multiple conditions which is below

```
select rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id, 
   ROUND (SUM (NVL (calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) as NELENGTH
                  from ne.mv_span@facid147 
                  where rj_network_type IN ('NLD', 'City', 'NLD-City', 'ENT', 'FEEDER', 'FTTx')
                  and rownum < 900000
and  rj_span_id is not null and rj_span_id <> '<Null>'
and  rj_intracity_link_id is not null and rj_intracity_link_id <> 'NA' and 
rj_intracity_link_id <> '-NA-'
group by rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id;
```

and its data I want to insert in below table which is

```html
Table name:- TBL_FIP_FETCH_NELENGTH

Name         Null Type           
------------ ---- -------------- 
ID                NUMBER(18,8)   
NE_LENGTH         NUMBER         
SPAN_LINK_ID      NVARCHAR2(100)
```

**note** `rj_span_id` and `rj_intracity_link_id` data can be inserted in one column which is `SPAN_LINK_ID`

Comment: I don't follow.  You have a query that returns three columns and a table with three columns that you want to insert the data into.  None of the column names in your query match the columns in your table so we have no idea which column from the query goes to which column in the table.  But then you say that two of the columns from your query should go to a single column in the table but don't tell us how you want that to happen (i.e. is exactly one going to be non-null and you want to pick that one?  Should we pick one arbitrarily?  Something else).

Comment: @nad what does "dblink" tag have to do with the question?

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes, We want to insert only non-null values. Yes the column names are not same in both the tables. The table `TBL_FIP_FETCH_NELENGTH` is manually created for storing values and checking with another table.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only one of rj_span_id and rj_intracity_link_id can be *not null*, then coalesce might be what you're looking for:

```
insert into target (span_link_id, ne_length)
(
select coalesce(rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id)
       ROUND (SUM (NVL (calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) as NELENGTH
from ne.mv_span@facid147 
where rj_network_type IN ('NLD', 'City', 'NLD-City', 'ENT', 'FEEDER', 'FTTx')
  and rownum < 900000
  and  rj_span_id is not null 
  and rj_span_id <> '<Null>'
  and rj_intracity_link_id is not null 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> 'NA' 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> '-NA-'
group by rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id
);
```

Or, perhaps `UNION` of two almost same queries - one would insert `rj_span_id`, and another `rj_intracity_link_id`.

```
insert into target (span_link_id, ne_length)
(
select rj_span_id, 
       ROUND (SUM (NVL (calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) as NELENGTH
from ne.mv_span@facid147 
where rj_network_type IN ('NLD', 'City', 'NLD-City', 'ENT', 'FEEDER', 'FTTx')
  and rownum < 900000
  and rj_span_id is not null 
  and rj_span_id <> '<Null>'
  and rj_intracity_link_id is not null 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> 'NA' 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> '-NA-'
group by rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id
union all
select rj_intracity_link_id, 
       ROUND (SUM (NVL (calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) as NELENGTH
from ne.mv_span@facid147 
where rj_network_type IN ('NLD', 'City', 'NLD-City', 'ENT', 'FEEDER', 'FTTx')
  and rownum < 900000
  and rj_span_id is not null 
  and rj_span_id <> '<Null>'
  and rj_intracity_link_id is not null 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> 'NA' 
  and rj_intracity_link_id <> '-NA-'
group by rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id
);
```

I don't know where is target table's `ID` column supposed to be populated, though.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo - use `insert into target (span_link_id, ne_length)` instead; the way it was, it looks like you tried to insert a string into a NUMBER column.

Comment: Which one of them do you want? If any, take e.g. MAX (and put remaining column from the SELECT column list into the GROUP BY clause).

Comment: Something like that; and `GROUP BY coalesce(rj_span_id, rj_intracity_link_id)`

Comment: Sure, if it is related to this question. If not, ask another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242126/discussion-between-nad-and-littlefoot).